# Notepad++ Auto-Complete not working with custom xml for specific filetype

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++

The auto-complete function of `Notepad++` works fine for file types such as `PHP` and `CSS` that are included by default. But I cannot get it to work at all for `DO` files from Stata. A simple `do.xml` includes the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>
<NotepadPlus>
    <AutoComplete>
        <KeyWord name="xtreg" func="yes">
            <Overload retVal="void">
                <Param name="void"/>
            </Overload>
        </KeyWord>
    </AutoComplete>
</NotepadPlus>
```

And I store it correctly under `plugins/APIs`. But it does not work at all for `DO` files. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, thank you, that works! Do you maybe also know how to create autoclose for custom created tags in npp (`View->User-Defined Dialogue...` option)? I mean those are usual `html` tags, I just colored them the new way and saved it as a user defined language. As I use Python `mako` templates I had to create my own definition for `.mak` and `.mako` file extensions. But after that I lost the possibility of autoclose from `TextFX` plugin. It doesn't know now that '.mako' and '.mak' are still the same '.html'. Don't you know occasionally how to get it back or set my own new one? )

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I figured the problem out: The name of the language must be identical to the name of the auto-complete `xml`. So if the name of the language is `Stata`, the name of the autocomplete file must be `Stata.xml`.

edit: Link to documentation: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Editing_Configuration_Files#Autocompletion.2C_aka_API.2C_files

> API files are located in the plugins\APIs\ subfolder of the Notepad++ installation folder. These files are optional: you need only one for each language for which you'll use Auto Completion or calltips. They are also supported for User Defined Languages, and bear the name <Language name>.xml.